# Placing multiple condition on if-statement

Tags: php, if-statement

I am having confusion in if statement

I have like

```
    if(hello==0 || bye==0)
    {
    echo 'error';
    }
```

but if

`hello==1 || bye==0` OR `hello==0 || bye==1`

then it should `echo 'fine';`

is their any process by which i can put this type of condition in if statement ??

**EDIT**

```
$numbers1=0;
$numbers2=0;

if(numbers1==0 || numbers2==0){
$percentage1 = ($numbers2 / ($numbers2 + $numbers1)) * 100;
$parcentage2 = ($numbers1 / ($numbers2 + $numbers1)) * 100;
}
```

This is why i can do fine clause as main statement

```
Warning: Division by zero
```

Comment: So, are you trying to `echo 'fine';` when *exactly one* of the two variables is `1`? Or are you also allowing both variables to be `1`?

Comment: ya i should edit it it must show error only if both the two variables shows 0

Comment: It usually helps if you add a tag for the actual language you're using, as the syntax you've posted applies to more than one. (You can [edit] your question to do so now.) If we know what language you're using, it helps you get an answer more quickly.

Comment: @user2615947 then why not just put `echo 'fine';` in the `else` clause?

Comment: Dennis yea :P but that echo i can't do that but the 0 and 1 are numbers

Comment: @user2615947 wait, what's wrong with `if (hello == 0 || bye == 0) { echo 'error'; } else { echo 'fine';}`?

Comment: :-) Thanks, but as I said, you should [edit] your question and provlde a tag that says that; it makes it so people can actually see it.

Comment: lol. Don't shout please.

Comment: hehehe i thought no one was seeing  :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you could just do

```
if (($numbers1 + $numbers2) != 0)
    echo 'fine';
else
    echo 'error';
```

to make sure the result of `$numbers1` and `$numbers2` isn't zero before dividing by it.

Comment: SORRY I HAVE EDITED PLEASE HAVE A LOOK

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want:

```
if($hello==1 || $bye==1)
{
    echo 'fine';
}
else
{
    echo 'error';
}
```

Comment: This still doesn't explain why the OP is getting a divide by 0 error.

Comment: SORRY I HAVE EDITED PLEASE HAVE A LOOK WHY I CANNOT ECHO FINE LIKE THAT.

Comment: Cole "Cole9" Johnson - Thats the main problem :(

Comment: @user2615947 don't edit your question to ask something else. Edit it to be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully at your conditions.

This works if there are no other possible values other than 0 or 1 (best to use a bool in this case probably)

```
if($hello==0 || $bye==0)
{
echo 'error';
}
else
{
echo 'fine';
}
```

If you want to guard against a null value then just use the isset() in your conditional.

Comment: SORRY I HAVE EDITED PLEASE HAVE A LOOK

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to avoid division by zero which can occur when both `$number1` ***and*** `$number2` are zero.

```
if (0 === $number1 && 0 === $number2)
{
   // division by zero
}
else
{
   // perform your calculation
}
```

One thing you did not make clear: Could either or both `$number1` and `$number2` be negative? If yes, then you might want to consider the condition where the sum of the numbers are zero (as per @sbat's suggestion).

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $numbers1!= 0 || $numbers2 != 0){
$percentage1 = ($numbers2 / ($numbers2 + $numbers1)) * 100;
$parcentage2 = ($numbers1 / ($numbers2 + $numbers1)) * 100;
}

else
{
echo 'error';

}
```

**Note** that you are missing the dollar sign before  numbers1 and numbers2 variables in your if statement. Good Luck.